# Tried to create user using react firebase hook though sendEmailVerification(); added but with out verifying it create user: here is the code below:

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
const createUser = async () => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await updateProfile({ displayName });
    await sendEmailVerification();enter code here
}

 <button onClick={ async () => await createUser() }>Create User</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The user will receive en email with a verification link.

Clicking this link will verify this user.

However, the user is created even without verification in the database. This is normal.

But: One can check the field `emailVerified` of the `user` object.

It should more or less look something like this, for example if the user tries to login without having the email address verified:

```
final credential = await 
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

if( credential.user.emailVerified == false ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable user after he will create account using Firebase Functions and firebase-admin SDK. If user verify email account, you can enable his account same using Firebase Functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
const createUser = async () => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await sendEmailVerification();enter code here
    if(user.emailVerfied === true){
    await updateProfile({ displayName });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers